# Eclipse error … 'cannot be resolved to a type'

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run a project using Eclipse IDE.
The project was created in 2015, and I am trying to use the commands that are still available on the internet. 
I am stuck on the following error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: currently
    Database cannot be resolved to a type
    The method bind(Class<Database>) from the type AbstractModule refers to the missing type Database
    Database cannot be resolved to a type
    The method bind(Class<RouteRepository>) from the type AbstractModule refers to the missing type RouteRepository
    RouteRepository cannot be resolved to a type
    RouteRepository cannot be resolved to a type
    The method bind(Class<SimulationRepository>) from the type AbstractModule refers to the missing type SimulationRepository
    SimulationRepository cannot be resolved to a type
    SimulationRepository cannot be resolved to a type
    The method bind(Class<MeasurementRepository>) from the type AbstractModule refers to the missing type MeasurementRepository
    MeasurementRepository cannot be resolved to a type
    MeasurementRepository cannot be resolved to a type
```

COuld you please give me any advices that could help me solving this issue?

I have already completed the following steps:

1. Installed Java jdk-8.0.242.08 and Java jre1.8.0_241;
2. Installed Eclipse IDE and the required softwares: Eclipse Git Team Provider; JGit; Maven Integration for Eclipse; Web; XML; Java EE.
3. Cloned GIT repository from: https://github.com/andreaswolf/graphhopper and https://github.com/andreaswolf/roadhopper
4. Import Existing Maven Projects.
5. Run a new JAVA application program with the following characteristics:

Main class: info.andreaswolf.roadhopper.server.RoadHopperServer

VM options: -Djetty.port=8989 -Dconfig.file=./roadhopper/application.conf - Dorientdb.config.file=./roadhopper/orientdb/orientdb-server-config.xml - DORIENTDB_HOME=./roadhopper/orientdb/

Program arguments: config=./config.properties

Working directory: Path to GraphHopper

Answer (score 0):

Probably the dependency that contains the classes Database, RouteRepository, SimulationRepository, MeasurementRepository did not uploads from maven repository, or local repository, or you did not add it dependency to your main project.

- Could you check this classes and figure out where did they come from.
- Then check it's source in pom.xml file as dependencies or check in build path configuration as source library.

Comment: Hello G.Rustam.
I checked the file RouteRepository.scala, and found the following commands that I assumed are defining the classes.

(1) import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
(2) import scala.collection.mutable

I also checked pom.xml, and noticed that (1) slf4j-api and (2) scala-library files are available on its Dependencies, and they contain  LoggerFactory.class and MutableList.class respective.

Are there any other checks that I could do, in order to define the issue root cause?